# Android - Why would Switch button on CursorAdaptor reset button immediately after a change

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to update a boolean value in a database table, based on a Switch. A ListView holds a list of languages with an "Install" Switch button for each. My CursorAdapter is displaying the list and the switches. I've set OnCheckedChangeListeners for each Switch. When I select one of the Switches, it briefly shows it as being switched on, but immediately reverts back to "off." In my logging, I see that the value is set to "true" and that this is sent to the DatabaseProvider to update the database. But then immediately thereafter, I see another log output that the value is false, which is then sent to the DatabaseProvider in another update.

CursorAdapter:

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public final TextView nameView;
    public final Switch installSwitch;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.language_textview);
        installSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.installed_switch);
    }
}

public LanguageAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_language, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    long languageId = cursor.getLong(0);
    String word = cursor.getString(1);
    boolean langInstalled = Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(2));
    viewHolder.nameView.setText(word);
    viewHolder.installSwitch.setChecked(langInstalled);
    viewHolder.installSwitch.setTag(languageId);

    viewHolder.installSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            long languageId = (long) buttonView.getTag();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(TranslationContract.LanguageEntry.COLUMN_INSTALLED, isChecked);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onChecked, langID: " + languageId + " isChecked: " + isChecked);
            buttonView.getContext().getContentResolver().update(TranslationContract.LanguageEntry.CONTENT_URI, cv, TranslationContract.LanguageEntry._ID+"=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(languageId)});
       }
    });
}
```

DatabaseProvider:

```
public int update(
        Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    int rowsUpdated;

    switch (match) {
        case LANGUAGES:
            rowsUpdated = db.update(LanguageEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Updating languages: " + values.toString());
            break;
 }
```

Log:

```
07-13 21:39:32.785    LanguageAdapter﹕ onChecked, langID: 2 isChecked: true
07-13 21:39:32.800    DatabaseProvider﹕ Updating languages: installed=true
07-13 21:39:32.813    LanguageAdapter﹕ onChecked, langID: 2 isChecked: false
07-13 21:39:32.825    DatabaseProvider﹕ Updating languages: installed=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging, I've discovered two issues:

First, onCheckChanged seems to be called twice always, which is perhaps an android bug? See the following posts: 
[onCheckedChanged fired multiple times, Listview with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188643/oncheckedchanged-fired-multiple-times-listview-with-checkbox) and 
[CheckBox changes value twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913687/checkbox-changes-value-twice)

Instead, use onClickListener.

The second issue here is incorrect handling of boolean values between the DB cursor and the java code. SQLite doesn't have a native BOOLEAN type, so values are stored and returned as integers 0 or 1. They need to be evaluated and then converted to a java boolean value.

The corrected code would be:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    long languageId = cursor.getLong(0);
    String word = cursor.getString(1);
    boolean langInstalled = cursor.getInt(2)>0; //convert DB 1 or 0 to java boolean
    viewHolder.nameView.setText(word);
    viewHolder.installSwitch.setChecked(langInstalled);
    viewHolder.installSwitch.setTag(languageId);
    viewHolder.installSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CompoundButton button = (CompoundButton) v;
            long languageId = (long) button.getTag();
            boolean isChecked = button.isChecked();
            int dbBoolean = 0;
            if (button.isChecked()) {
                dbBoolean = 1;
            }
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(TranslationContract.LanguageEntry.COLUMN_INSTALLED, dbBoolean);
            button.getContext().getContentResolver().update(TranslationContract.LanguageEntry.CONTENT_URI, cv, TranslationContract.LanguageEntry._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(languageId)});
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```